# Delete all fields where id == userId in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase: "^10.4.0" and I want to delete all messages **where id == userId** but I'm getting an error **FIRESTORE (10.4.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state**. Those methods outside the class (commented as //2 and //3) are just to show what else I tried, normally they are not in my code.

createMessage and getMessages works as it should

My Firestore looks like this

```
"messages" > doc.id > 
{
  contentBody: "text",
  createdAt: timestamp,
  id: userId,
  turn: true,
}
```

Here's the code

```
import "../firebase";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  deleteDoc,
  getFirestore,
  where,
  query,
  serverTimestamp,
  orderBy,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore();

export class MessagesDB {
  constructor() {
    this.messagesCollRef = collection(db, "messages");

    this.createMessage = async (msgData) => {
      const newData = {
        id: msgData.id,
        contentBody: msgData.contentBody,
        turn: msgData.turn,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      };
      await addDoc(this.messagesCollRef, newData);
    };

    this.getMessages = async (userId) => {
      const q = query(
        this.messagesCollRef,
        where("id", "==", userId),
        orderBy("createdAt")
      );
      const data = await getDocs(q).catch((e) => console.log(e));
      return data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
    };

    //1
    this.deleteMessages = async (userId) => {
      const q = query(this.messagesCollRef, where("id", "==", userId));
      const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
      if (snapshot.docs.length === 0) {
        return [];
      }
      await deleteDoc(q);
    };
  }
}

//2
this.deleteMessages = async (userId) => {
  const q = query(this.messagesCollRef, where("id", "==", userId));
  await deleteDoc(q);
};

//3
this.deleteMessages = async (userId) => {
  const q = query(this.messagesCollRef, where("id", "==", userId));
  const data = await getDocs(q).catch((e) => console.log(e));

  data.forEach(async (doc) => {
    await deleteDoc(this.messagesCollRef, data);
  });
};
```

Comment: I answered on why #1 doesn't work below, but now notice you have multiple approaches in your code. (in the future please limit yourself to just one approach: the one that you thought should work)

Answer (score 3):

This won't work:

```
deleteDoc(q)
```

The Firestore `deleteDoc` operation requires a `DocumentReference`, because it works on an individual document. You can't pass it a query and expect it to delete all documents matching that query.

So you will have to:

1. Execute the query
2. Loop over the documents
3. Delete each document in turn

In code that'd be:

```
const q = query(this.messagesCollRef, where("id", "==", userId));
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);

for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
  await deleteDoc(doc.ref);
};
```

The above code waits for each individual delete to complete before starting on the next one.

If you'd instead want the deletes to execute in parallel, but wait for all of them to complete before doing something else, that'd be:

```
const q = query(this.messagesCollRef, where("id", "==", userId));
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
const promises = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => deleteDoc(doc.ref));
await Promise.all(promises);
```

This will be faster than waiting for each individual delete, so you'll typically want to use this - unless you have a specific reason to wait for each delete individually.